# prompting a user through C# program

Tags: c#

Please can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code below I just cannot display anything.

```
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine"Hello World!";                  
            Console.WriteLine"Press any key to exit.";
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dear you have written a wrong code here is the correct one 
and you forgot to add this ()

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Hello 
    {
        static void Main() 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            // Keep the console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the WriteLine() method correctly.

Change it to:

```
static void Main() 
   { 
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Keep in mind, when calling a method, don't forget the ().